Why it takes 7 seconds to reserve ~200GB of huge pages at boot?
I have a server with 300G of RAM and I'm preallocating ~192G of it as huge pages by passing  hugepagesz=1G hugepages=192 args to kernel command line.
As a result, I see these  lines in dmesg:
[    1.276475\] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:off, heap free:off
[    8.102710\] Memory: 2973348K/301621240K available (14349K kernel code, 9611K rwdata, 8492K rodata, 2516K init, 20268K bss, 206226124K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)

Without such preallocation there is not such gap in timestamps. Anybody has a clue why it takes so much for kernel to reserve  huge pages?
